# 3rd party application for windows service failover

Tags: service, failover

We have a traditional client server application. The server side is a plain "old" windows service. To achieve higher availability in a rather quick way it would be ok to start with the service installed on two different servers. The services should however not both be active at the same time, so if the service fails for some reason on the first server, or the first server goes down, the second one should take over. 
This can be done with a windows cluster, but this is fairly expensive solutuion because it has hardware and OS (win enterprise for example) requirements.
Is there any good 3rd party software that can handle this task of "monitoring" services and switch over services?

Thx in advance,

Kind regards, 
Wim

Comment: How do the clients locate the service?

Comment: they use server name or IP address, but network load balancer can redirect to the correct service on failover.

Answer (score 0):

### A Game Of Static Poker : "decentralized fail-over"

#### overview

- At entering the room you pick a random card.
- If you find someone with the same card you leave & come back.
- If you leave & come back you need to pick a new card.
- The one with the highest card in the room at any given time speaks.

#### Basic Implementation

- you have x services running on x servers
- when the service starts it picks a random number between say int.Min and int.Max
- in the service configuration you specify every host running the service, ex " http://internal.server1.com:8282, http://internal.server2.com:8282, http://internal.server3.com:8282"
- each service starts an embedded http server (ex using http://nancyfx.org) listening to the hosts specified in the application configuration and serves the chosen number at /
- when the services are running they endlessly poll these hosts for the maximum value
- if the current service number is the highest of the maximum found value it switches to the active service, otherwise it switches to passive